# Anyone have a favorite Python coding style enforcer?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm trying to find a Python coding style enforcer (tool, not person!). Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I only know [`pylint`](http://www.logilab.org/857), but it is not an automatic code formatter, rather a marking tool.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget PEP8, both the PEP8 style guide (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and the [tool](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8)

Not a lint like tool, but keeps your style in line with the main python community.

yapf (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yapf) is super cool, reformats your code to be pep8 compliant. Very handy

Answer (score 0):

[`pyflakes`](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodPyflakes) is like `pylint` but faster.